# How to Select an Updated sql, so that I can get the data of the new update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want it to be something like that, where I can update and have the query 
together

Sample query:

```
select top 1 Id, Name, Title
from People
where Id = 2
update Title = 'Manager'
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Google: sql update statement

Comment: Just refer this link - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: sql server management studio

Comment: Developer_29. that doesn't help. I want to walk away with the data and use it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Can you explain it in plain English? Otehrwise, a small example could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what you really want...

**IF** you want to **primarily** update your data, and get back the updated data rows from the `UPDATE` statement - try something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.People
SET Title = 'Manager'
OUTPUT Inserted.Id, Inserted.Name, Inserted.Title
WHERE Id = 2
```

When you `UPDATE`, you get the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo table - like in a trigger - which refer to the data *before* the `UPDATE` (`Deleted`), and to the data *after* the `UPDATE` (`Inserted`) and you can output any combination of those values. This is a regular result set - like from a `SELECT`.

On the other hand, if you want to **primarily** select, and then update the selected data - try something like this:

```
WITH SelectedData AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Id, Name, Title
    FROM dbo.People
    WHERE Id = 2
)
UPDATE SelectedData
SET Title = 'Manager'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-output-into-with-an-update-statement)

You can use a table variable to store the data you need from the update to use later.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(  
    id int,  
    Name varchar(100),  
    OldTitle varchar(100),
    NewTitle varchar(100))

UPDATE People
SET Title = 'Manager'
OUTPUT inserted.Id,  
       deleted.Name,  
       deleted.Title,  
       inserted.Title
INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE Id = 2

SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar
```